# "no such field as `OGR_GEOMETRY'" when changing Multipolygon to Polygon with altering geometry in shapefile

Tags: shapefile, geometry, ogr, ogr2ogr, bash

The attempt is to change from multipolygon to polygon (shapefile) using:

```
ogrinfo tmpem122.shp -sql "alter table tmpem122 alter column OGR_GEOMETRY type geometry(polygon, 4326) using st_geometryn(geometry,1)"
```

I get this error message:

> ERROR 1: alter table tmpem122 alter column OGR_GEOMETRY type
> geometry(polygon, 4326) using st_geometryn(geometry,1) failed, no such
> field as `OGR_GEOMETRY'.

but according to `ogrinfo -sql "select * from tmpem122" tmpem122.shp`, the geometry column is `OGR_GEOMETRY` (or `_ogr_geometry_`):

```
Layer name: tmpem122
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 17
Extent: ...
...
...
Geometry Column = _ogr_geometry_
gid: String (10.0)
...
```

What would it be wrong? Please find the file sample here for your testing: https://file.io/U4XnvYSb69lp

Comment: I would expect a shapefile geometry column to be called `the_geom`

Comment: Try replacing `alter column OGR_GEOMETRY` with `alter column SHAPE` ..or whatever the geometry field is named in your .shp file ..which probably should be `SHAPE` in order to avoid various oddball problems here and there. If your .shp file's geometry field is named something else, it's very possible this is the root of your issue.

Comment: the same error message here after changing the column name, would you mind to test the sample file? here you can find it: https://file.io/U4XnvYSb69lp

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68591393/820534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a solution to the `no such field as OGR_GEOMETRY` problem but that is irrelevant because it is not possible to do what you are trying. Shapefile specification does not make difference between polygons and multipolygons. `ALTER TABLE` will not work because it tries to change the field definitions of the table. What you seem to want to do is to update the geometries.

Try this instead

```
ogrinfo -sql "update polygonz set geometry=st_geometryn(geometry,1)" polygonz.shp -dialect sqlite
```

Notice that you must use the SQLite dialect because only that has the ST_GeometryN function and for SQLite dialect the name of the geometry field is usually `geometry`.